# Load Tawny package on R 2.15.3

Tags: r, package

I have R version 2.15.3
When i try to load it:

```
library (tawny)
```

i receive this response:

> package ‘parser’ could not be loaded

The package Parser in not on Cran anymore, it seems a dead project!
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parser/index.html

If i try to manual install parser_0.1.tar.gz i receive an error and can't install it.

The question is. 
Is today impossible to use tawny package?
Is there a way to solve this problem that seems caused by parser package?

Thank you very much

Comment: If it's feasible for you to switch to R 3.0, it seems to work fine...

Comment: Switch to R 3.0 is the only solution?

Comment: The problem is `futile.logger` package (a `tawny` dependency) for R < 3.0 depends on parser package that is not on CRAN anymore. You can install it but you need to compile it first. In fact the packaged you've tried to install is not directly "installable" but needs compilation... in windows to compile a package you need to something more ([RTools etc](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html)). Switching to R 3.0 is a nice shortcut :)

Comment: Yes i understand. I tried R 3.0 but noticed that other packages doesn't work :-( I'm not a programmer, so i don't know nothing about Rtools etc. Does exists someone that have done compilation and gives his work to newbie like me?

Comment: Ok, I compiled the `parser` package for you (R 2.15.3) [>download link<](http://we.tl/PRqDFdMoAa). Anyway, it seems strange to me that other packages don't work in R 3.0. I suggest you to install the packages using CRAN, if they're not available it usually means they have been replaced by other packages...

Comment: The problem is the namespace requirement in R 2.14 caused a lot of orphan packages that didn't have a namespace to stop working.  This is why you will see a lot of packages that no longer work.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're incredibly kind